# Btrfs snapshot marked as deleted

Tags: btrfs, snapshot

I am using Btrfs v3.12 and each time I delete a snapshot it is not deleted, marked as "DELETED" but the global size of the volume doesn't change.

I have never seen that in older version of BTRFS.

```
/sbin/btrfs subvolume delete /data/snapshot/my_snap
/data/numbackup# btrfs subvolume list /data
    ID 258 gen 134150 top level 5 path snapshot
    ID 4889 gen 92998 top level 0 path DELETED
```

Is that a new and normal behavior of btrfs?
Best regards

Answer (score 1):

The subvolume was correctly marked as deleted and will be cleaned at a later time. This is the same behavior as before Trusty.

Before Trusty, `btrfs subvolume list` was just omitting the deleted, not-yet-cleaned subvolumes in the output. In Oct 2013, this was changed to list them as DELETED rather than skipping them, so this change is in Trusty's btrfs-tools (3.12) but not in previous Ubuntu releases.

Comment: Very interesting behavior. But some of the snapshot are marked as DELETED for now 2 Weeks!! Is it possible to force it?

Comment: `btrfs filesystem sync` should do that, but it brings no advantage, besides updating the space usage output of `btrfs filesytem df`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the space occupied by the DELETED snapshots is available for new snapshots only after a `btrfs filesystem sync`